# how to read model in afterModel in ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Server returning this json

```
{"auths":[{"id":0,"email":"abc","password":"","logged":false}]}
```

In ember debugger for chrome I can see the model filled.

```
EMSystem.Auth = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string'),
    logged: DS.attr('boolean')
});

EMSystem.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('auth');
    },
    afterModel: function(model) {
        console.log(model.get('logged'));
        //logic to change the route if user is logged
    }
});
```

But for console.log I am getting undefined. How to access the model in after model?

Comment: Did u inspect the model object you get in afterModel. I think you might be getting an array since you are using the 'findAll' method. If thats the case, the this might work model.get('firstObject.logged')

Comment: Thanks for comment. No matter it's find or findAll your solution works well. But sorry accepting the other answer as that is in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll('type')` and `find('type')` are synonymous and both return a collection.  If you'd like to print out the `logged` value from each item you can use `forEach`/`for` to iterate over the collection.

```
afterModel: function(model) {
  model.forEach(function(record){
    console.log(record.get('logged'));
    //logic to change the route if user is logged
  });
}
```